# Prolog constraint

Tags: prolog, constraints, clpfd

I have 3 Constraints for a List:

1. list ins 1..9
2. all_different(list)
3. lists in the list --> I get some lists from the list. every list from the list has to fulfill the constraint to be gapless. for example:

   List1 = [1,3,2,4]; 
   List2=[3,2,1]; 
   List3= [5,7,6] 
   **WRONG**: List4=[1,4,3]

**1 Question**: You have an idea to set constraint 3? I would sort the lists and check for: Element1=Element2+1?

After all i want to use labeling([ff],list)

**2 Question**: I get a solution with labeling if i set contraint 3 like my idea?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. Stick to programs, your words are hard to understand.

Comment: i will edit my question tomorrow. first i have to finish my bachelorthesis. Sry for the bad question.

Comment: Are all lists within the list a list of only one element? If so, it's not clear why they are lists.

Comment: absolute right lurker, it was a mistake that the elemets were lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is along the lines of what you're looking for...

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

foo(L) :-
    Len in 1..9,    % lists of length 1 through 9
    length(L, Len),
    L ins 1..9,
    label(L),
    msort(L, LS),
    series(LS).

series([_]).
series([X,Y|T]) :- Y #= X + 1, series([Y|T]).
```

Since you are already constraining the list to a specific series behavior, indicating `all_different` would be redundant.

Another approach could be:

```
foo(L) :-
    [Fst,Lst] ins 1..9,
    Fst #=< Lst,
    Len #= Lst - Fst + 1,
    length(L, Len),
    label([Fst,Lst]),
    L ins Fst..Lst,
    all_different(L),
    label(L).
```

These predicates generate all possible lists meeting the criteria, and should succeed if and only if the given list meets the criteria.

Comment: Regarding the first snippet: There is `in/2` and `indomain/1` for single finite domain variables. And: Replacing `=:=` by `#=` would make `series/2` more general.

Comment: @mat yeah thanks. I'm not used to using SWI. I'll correct. Originally, I had `#=` but didn't think it mattered since the variables were already instantiated/labeled. But I agree with your comment.

Comment: with `indomain/1`, I mean you can replace `label([Len])` by `indomain(Len)` in both snippets.

Comment: @mat ah OK, thanks. I wasn't familiar with `indomain/1` before. Is there an advantage besides not having to represent a single variable as a list as in `label/1`?

Comment: I find it a bit easier to read, because it immediately makes clear that only a single variable is involved. (The efficiency difference is completely negligible in my opinion.)

Comment: the answer helped me a lot. BUT the problem is i want to solve [Str8ts](http://www.str8ts.com/). If i check the constraints for the rows first. all undefined variables will be defined after ill check with foo. then i want to check the columns of the puzzle. but  foo will fail, cause i already defined the variables by foo all rows. is it possible to set the constraint without label it. and after i foo rows and columns, label all?

Comment: @Hans, ok your original question wasn't specifically formulated to handle all the conditions you're now describing. But, yes, you can defer the `label(L)`. The `label([Fst,Lst])` is needed for the following `ins` to work.

Comment: what do you mean by the following `ins` and `label([first,last])`

Comment: @Hans see the second predicate in my answer.

Comment: @lurker if i use labeling after i set the constraints for the rows, i get the error: `Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`  This means the domain for the variables is not set or?

Comment: @lurker this is my predicate for constraint 3 now: `foo(L) :-
    [Fst,Lst] ins 1..9,
    Fst #=< Lst,
    Len #= Lst - Fst + 1,
    length(L, Len),
    label([Fst,Lst]),
    L ins Fst..Lst,
    all_different(L).`

Comment: @Hans your error message must point to a line number which is not inside your new `foo/1`. Something else you're doing outside of `foo/1` is causing the error. I believe I answered your original question properly as stated, and now you are introducing new questions. You should mark this one answered and create e new question.

Answer (score 2):

This might also be what you are looking for. No sorting, just use of `maximum` and `minimum`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

listl( LSize, List ) :-
  length( List, LSize ),
  domain(List, 1, 9),

  maximum( MaxL, List ),
  minimum( MinL, List ),

  all_different(List),
  LSize #= MaxL - MinL + 1,

  labeling( [], List ).
```

With a small test:

```
| ?- listl( 4, L ).
L = [1,2,3,4] ? ;
L = [1,2,4,3] ? ;
L = [1,3,2,4] ? ;
L = [1,3,4,2] ? 
yes
| ?-
```

Disclaimer: The question was hard to understand.